# SQL Multiple Joins not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, join

I have following query not working when I try to join all 4 tables (It is taking over an hour to run, I have to eventually kill the query without any data being returned). 
It works when Table 1,2 & 3 are joined AND Then If I try Table 1,2 & 4 join but not when I attempt to join all 4 tables below.

```
Select * From
    (Select 
        R.ID, R.MId, R.RId, R.F_Name, R.F_Value, FE.FullEval, M.Name, RC.CC     
        FROM Table1 as R
        Inner Join Table2 FE
                ON R.ID = FE.RClId and R.MId = FE.MId and R.RId = FE.RId
            Inner Join Table3 as M
                 ON R.MId = M.MId and FE.MId = M.MId
               Inner Join Table4 as RC
                  ON R.RId = RC.RId and FE.RId = RC.RId and FE.Date = RC.Date

    ) AS a
```

NOTE: 
1) RId is not available in table3.
2) MId is not available in table4.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Try using a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: what do you mean by `not working as expected`?

Comment: What's the issue? Are you receiving an empty table? Is the query crashing?

Comment: Sorry for missing that piece of information. It is taking over an hour to run, I have to eventually kill the query without any data being returned.

Comment: If you want to improve the performance of this query, then please supplement information about database you are using (oracle, slq-server, mysql etc.) becaouse performance-improving  methods sometines differ for each product. Please also generate a query plan (explain plan, excution plan) of the query and append it to the question. Also appending `[query-optimization]` tag to your question might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks krokodilko _ Unfortunately I don't have permissions to View a query plan in SQL Server Management Studio. I will add the tag.

Comment: Thanks  WEI_DBA . I tried LEFT JOIN and its been an hr without any results. I have to kill the query now.

Comment: Is there any RId in Table 3?

Comment: Hi Ferdinand Gaspar. No, there is no RId in Table 3. That's the only table without RId. Same goes for MId, MId is in all tables except for Table 4. Thanks.

Comment: `I don't have permissions to View a query plan` - you have got an assigment to optimize the query, but you don't have permissions. Then ask your boss for permissions, tell him that it's almost impossible to do this job without an access to basic tools..

Comment: Seems to me some of the join criteria ofr the table3 and table4 is redundant.  .`FROM Table1 as R
Inner Join Table2 FE
  ON R.ID = FE.RClId 
 and R.MId = FE.MId 
 and R.RId = FE.RId
Inner Join Table3 as M
  ON FE.MId = M.MId
Inner Join Table4 as RC
  ON FE.RId = RC.RId 
 and FE.Date = RC.Date`  No need to join to r and fe if r and fe must be equal.

Comment: Thanks xQbert. Yes, I tried that as well. I added some redundant(s) because it was making prior joins for table1,2,3 AND table1,2,4 a tad bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you don't have permission to view the query plan, try breaking down into each table join. You can also check which table join is taking time to retrieve records. From there, you can investigate the data why it's taking time. It may be because of non-availability of column keys in Table 3 and Table 4?

```
WITH Tab1_2 AS
(SELECT r.ID, r.MId, r.RId, r.F_Name, r.F_Value, fe.FullEval, fe.date
   FROM Table1 as r
  INNER JOIN Table2 fe
     ON r.ID = fe.RClId
    AND r.MId = fe.MId
    AND r.RId = fe.RId
  WHERE ... -- place your conditions if any
),

Tab12_3 AS
(SELECT t12.*, m.Name
   FROM Tab1_2 t12
  INNER JOIN Table3 as m
     ON t12.MId = m.MId
  WHERE ... -- place your conditions if any
),

Tab123_4 AS
(SELECT t123.ID, t123.MId, t123.RId, t123.F_Name, t123.F_Value, t123.FullEval, rc.CC
   FROM Tab12_3 t123
  INNER JOIN Table4 as rc
     ON t123.RId = rc.RId 
    AND t123.Date = rc.Date
  WHERE ... -- place your conditions if any
)

SELECT *
  FROM Tab123_4 t1234
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the recommendation.
Unfortunately, after making changes and running for almost 1 hr there were no results so I had to stop the query.
Note: I can join Table 1,2 & 3 and I can see results in 2 mins. I can also join table 1,2 & 4 and I can see results in just over 2 mins.
Its just when I try joining all 4 tables then I am at loss!! :(

Comment: I have finally ran the query for almost 2 hrs with following error:

Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'.